# How do I quickly find the proper fixes for the dependency chain suggested by npm audit?

Tags: security, npm, phantomjs, npm-audit

I'm participating an Open Source project which currently uses phantom.js as a dev dependency. `npm audit` shows that phantom.js has 13 vulnerabilites and some dependency chains are somewhat long:

```
  Moderate        Prototype Pollution

  Package         hoek

  Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

  Dependency of   phantomjs [dev]

  Path            phantomjs > request > hawk > sntp > hoek

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/566
```

I'm thinking of suggesting some updates to phantomjs and the underlaying packages, but the info provided by npm audit is not that helpful:

- they suggest that `hoek` 5.0.3 or later would be nice,
- but they don't show what version of `sntp` is used,
- and if there is a later version of `sntp` which uses a secure version of `hoek`,
- and the same for `hawk` and `request`

It may be true that updating `request` to some newer version will fix the vulnerability of phantomjs at once, without suggesting any updates to `hawk`, `sntp` or `hoek`, but figuring that sounds like a lot of manual work. Are there any tools that help finding the shortest possible way to fix a reported vulnerability?
(I understand that blind updating may actually introduce new bugs/other vulnerabilities, but at least we could get a suggestion how to proceed)